# settings.xml for maven 3.8.1

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I switched from Netbeans to Eclipse IDE for Java applications and remote debugging. The Maven project wizard generated a java project with the pom.xml and build.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>IntelligentHome</groupId>
  <artifactId>RaspberryPi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>RaspberryPi</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

<!--
    <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <archive>
                  <manifest>
                     <mainClass>IntelligentHome.RaspberryPi.App</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
               </archive>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
-->

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository> 
    <id>maven2</id> 
    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url> 
  </pluginRepository> 
</pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Executing the file using ANT build results in this Error

> [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Error resolving version for
> 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin': Plugin requires
> Maven version 3.0

executing

> mvn -version
> Apache Maven 3.6.3

list the current maven version. This version is also linked in the preferences of maven inside the IDE
[image]

Some research reveals that maven2 is no longer maintained and should not be used. For some reason the folder ./m2 is still in my home drive and used as user settings for the maven build
[image]

the settings.xml that is apparently used reads

```
 <settings xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
      <localRepository/>
      <interactiveMode/>
      <offline/>
      <pluginGroups/>
      <servers/>
      <mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>centralhttps</id>
          <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
          <name>Maven central https</name>
          <url>http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </mirror>
      </mirrors>
      <proxies/>
      <profiles/>
      <activeProfiles/>
   </settings>
```

a line linking something to maven2.

How do I change the settings.xml to the current maven version?
How does Eclipse changes the settings.xml when maven is upgraded?

When I remove all the plugins no errors are thrown and the .jar is executed on the target. This leads to another question: What do this plugins do when the program works fine without them?

Answer (score 0):

The folder $HOME/.m2 is used for both maven2 and maven3. How confusing? :-)
Unless you are doing something special, you can simply remove your settings.xml file.

Although you didn't ask, unless you have a specific need for Eclipse, I recommend IntelliJ community edition. Eclipse has to import the pom.xml into its own configuration. Netbeans and IntelliJ both work with mvn without this step. There is also a special maven plugin for Eclipse that you may want to use if you continue with Eclipse.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
```

That being said, I haven't touched Eclipse for a couple of years...

Comment: where do I integrate this plugin? Directly in the pom.xml

Comment: Adding this plugin leads to another error (Plugin requires Maven version 2.2.1). I have similar errors when buildiung the remote debug configuration with other plugins. I now wasted 2 days on configuration problems which did not occur on Netbeans, VSCode, VisualStudio or Labview. I think I will switch back to Netbeans or have a look at the advertised IntelliJ (the new institute uses Eclipse for some reason)